# How to put the arrow in Flow Chart in the middle of a rectangle with horizontal (not vertical) arrow direction

Tags: tikz-arrows, flow-charts

I am trying to build a flowchart in LaTeX and cannot make a pretty one! Here is where I am so far:

```
%styles
\tikzstyle{terminal1} = [terminal, draw, fill=red!40]
\tikzstyle{line}=[draw,-latex', thick]
\tikzstyle{decision1}=[draw, decision, fill = red!50]
\tikzstyle{process1}=[draw, process, fill=blue!30, text width=10 em, text centered, minimum height = 15 mm, node distance = 20mm]
\tikzstyle{predproc1}=[draw, predproc, fill=blue!30, text width=10 em, text centered, minimum height = 15 mm, node distance = 20mm]



\usepackage{flowchart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes,arrows,positioning,chains, shadows}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[process1](order){Order};
\node[predproc1, right of = order, yshift=30mm, xshift=60mm](generate_code){Generate Machining Code};
\node[predproc1, right of = order, yshift=-30mm, xshift=60mm](determine_tooling){Determine Tooling};
\node[process1, right of = order, xshift=100mm](machining_setup){Machining Setup};


\coordinate (point1) at (3.5cm,0);
\coordinate (point2) at (3.5cm,1cm);
\coordinate (point3) at (3.5cm,-3cm);

%arrows
%\path[line](user) --(start);
\draw[->](order) --(point1)--(point2) -| (generate_code.west);
\draw[->](order) --(point1)--(point3)-|(determine_tooling.west);
\draw[->](determine_tooling) -|(machining_setup);
\draw[->](generate_code) -|(machining_setup);
%\draw[->](process1)-| node [xshift=30mm,yshift=2mm]{yes}(user);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

1. Is there an easy way to tell LaTeX to find the middle of the rectangle and attach the arrow?
2. How can I solve the problem about arrowhead direction?
3. How can I increase the thickness of arrows? When I use `path[line]`, one of the lines disappear! Please also check that.

Thanks a lot. Please keep your answer close to my code if possible. I know there are many ways to make a flow chart; I am quite new to LaTeX and am looking for an easy one.

Comment: I highly appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

i suspect that you like to draw something like this:

[image]

in your *mwe* i made the following changes:

- remove all not used libraries
- for positioning i use syntax of `positioning` library (`above right=of ...` --> `above right=of ...`, consequently `node distances` are now determined between node orders and not between nodes' centers)
- `node distance` is determined centrally (for all nodes)
- i introduce shorter (but meaningless) names of nodes
- horizontal and vertical arrows always start and ends at middle of nodes (simplified explanation)

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning}
\usepackage{flowchart}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 2mm and 4mm,
  process1/.style = {draw, process, fill=blue!30,
                    minimum height = 15mm, text width=8 em, align=flush center},
preprocess/.style = {draw, predproc, fill=blue!30,
                    minimum height = 15mm, text width=8 em, align=flush center},
      line/.style = {-latex', thick}
                        ]
% noides
\node[process1] (n1) {Order};
    \coordinate[right=of n1.east] (n2);
\node[preprocess, above right=of n2 |- n1.north]   (n3) {Generate Machining Code};
\node[preprocess, below right=of n2 |- n1.south]   (n4) {Determine Tooling};
\node[process1, below right=of n3] (n5) {Machining Setup};
% arrows
\draw[line] (n1)  -- (n2) |- (n3);
\draw[line] (n2) |- (n4);
%
\draw[line] (n3) -| (n5);
\draw[line] (n4) -| (n5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```